# Change response body in azure api management service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am testing out a `GET` request with APIm using [json placeholder api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and cannot replace my response body. Any help is appreciated!

JSON response:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
}
```

Here is my policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
 <base />
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)">
    <set-body>@{
        var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
        response["id"] = "Hello World!";
        return response.ToString();
      }
    </set-body>
  </when>
</choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I end up with this error:

> set-body (7.739 ms) {
> "messages": [
> {
> "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
> "expression": "\n        var response = context.Response.Body.As();\n        response["id"] = 2;\n
> return response.ToString();\n      ",
> "details": "The message body is not a valid JSON. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line
> 0, position 0.\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings
> settings)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.AsJObject(Stream
> stream, Encoding encoding, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.As[T](Boolean
> preserveContent)"
> },
> "Expression evaluation failed. The message body is not a valid JSON. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path
> '', line 0, position 0.\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings
> settings)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.AsJObject(Stream
> stream, Encoding encoding, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.As[T](Boolean
> preserveContent)",
> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0."
> ] }

### update 1:

Executing this policy and shows that the body is `null`. Is there a way to wait for the response body? When I debug it within vscode and step through it, I'm getting the response successfully. Here's my new outbound policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-header name="Content-Type">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Accept">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
            JObject body = null;
        try {
            body = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
            return  "{\"id\":"+ @body["type"] + "}";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Response.Body);
        }
        }
        </set-body>
        </return-response>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

### Update 2

Added a trace:

```
<trace source="test">
    <message>@{
        return context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
    }</message>
</trace>
```

#### result of the trace:

```
test (0.006 ms)
"��\u0002\u0000 ���%\u001d�WV\rm%\n:\u0018�˫�y�ȁ[�P۝߁��>�\u0000�w9\u0015s\b�èS7���˻\u0013�\u0005늇>qs*��\f�\u0001"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the header to `Accept-Encoding: *` gave me a successful response. I thought `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` was enough for encoding. I need to do a deeper dive Accept-Encoding but when I saw the error in the trace, it looked like an encoding issue and that's how I arrived with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me, the header needed to be set in the request.  Here's a link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/95956